# Batch delete, update in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, updates, batch-processing

is it the best option to flush, clear session after a delete/update transaction?
Or session.save(deleted/updated instance) would work fine. I mean can save handle deletes and updates? And then batch flush, clear transactions in batch.
Or is batch option just to insert into tables?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate offical doc provides the guide lines for batch processing; you can found them [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).